# Anime: main character has control over time on cards and uses them to fight time monsters; characters lose memories if they speed up time

Tags: story-identification, anime

It's been a few years but in this anime the characters have an element which they control time on to fight, speeding up or slowing down time on said element, some include water, air, cards and school clothes.

They fight time monsters which take time from people, eventually killing them. The main character controls cards but if they speed up time on the cards they lose memories, fixed later in the anime.

Also the water user shows that the newer model of the 'gem' (can't remember what it was exactly) can speed up and slow down time on an element at the same time (can't remember if this character controlled water or air).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might want to check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) for asking anime identification questions; it might suggest some more details you can add to your question.  You should be more specific about how long ago "a few years" was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's *Chronos Ruler* (*Jikan no Shihaisha*, 2017).

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/chronos-ruler):

> We all wish we could go back in time, to turn back the clock and fix the past. But in this reality, that simple wish brings about something deadly—**demons that devour time! It’s up to a group of strong warriors who fight using time manipulation to destroy these blights.** Victor, Kiri, Mina, and Blaze have what it takes to maintain the balance of time as the chosen fighters—the Chronos Rulers.

[The Wikia](https://chronosruler.fandom.com/wiki/Chronos_Ruler) lists the elements used, including the cards and the rather unique "school uniform manipulation" you remembered:

> The term Chronos Ruler (クロノス·ルーラー, Kuronosu Rūrā) applies to individuals capable of manipulating the time. Each of them are able to rule over one object, which can range from elements of nature to simple playing cards. [...]
>
> Below is a list of Chronos Rulers along with their objects they ruled over.
>
> - Victor Putin (Cards)
> - Kiri Putin (Water)
> - Mina Putin (Wind)
> - Snake (Girls' School Uniform)
> - Blaze (Fire)

---

Found with the Google query `anime card fight element "steal * time" site:myanimelist.net/anime -wixoss`.

Comment: Thanks, been looking for this since i first saw it.